# i got this how do i solve it?Line 10: no viable alternative at input 'if'. Try to add line '//@version=2' to the top of your script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

```
// Calcule le VWAP sur une période de 10 jours
vwap = vwap(10)

// Définit les bandes de VWAP comme étant +/- 2 écart-types du VWAP
vwap_lower_band = vwap - stdev(vwap, 10) * 2
vwap_upper_band = vwap + stdev(vwap, 10) * 2

// Vérifie si le prix actuel est inférieur à la bande inférieure de VWAP
if (close < vwap_lower_band) then
  // Achete si le prix actuel est inférieur à la bande inférieure de VWAP
  strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

// Vérifie si le prix actuel est supérieur à la bande supérieure de VWAP
if (close > vwap_upper_band) then
  // Vends si le prix actuel est supérieur à la bande supérieure de VWAP
  strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

I expected to get an error as always.
I already added the version but i dont know how to solve the error

Answer (score 1):

Replace your :

```
if ... then
```

By

```
if ...
```

No 'then' in Pinescript v5

Answer (score 0):

As well as removing the "then" statement..

Add:

```
//version=5
strategy("My Script")
```

At the top of your code

---

Change:

```
vwap(10)
```

For:

```
ta.vwap(10)
```

---

Change:

```
stdev
```

For:

```
ta.stdev
```

Also, you might need to Tab those strategy.entry() functions in another tab :)